# Same news-detail clicking on different news on Ionic 4 (Newsapi)

Tags: ionic4, feed

I'm following a tutorial here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NJ9C7iY9350. Cannot understand why i'm doing click on a news and the news-detail is always the same, i'm checking my code and its the same as in the github. But don't know why cannot see the news-detail of every news, just remains the first news i do the click.

Attach my code:

NEWS

---

TS

```
    goToNews(article) {
    this.newsService.currentArticle = article;
    console.log(article)
    this.router.navigate(['/tabs/news-detail']);
}

    getNews() {
    this.newsService.getData(`top-headlines?countries=${this.selectedCountry}&category=technology`)
        .subscribe(data => {
            this.news = data;
            console.log(this.selectedCountry)
        })
}
```

HTML

```
    <ion-list *ngIf="!isResult">
    <ion-item *ngFor="let country of countries" (click)="selectCountry(country)">
        {{ country }}
    </ion-item>
</ion-list>
<ion-card *ngFor="let article of news?.articles" (click)="goToNews(article)">
    <ion-card-content>
        <ion-card-title>{{ article.title }}</ion-card-title>
    </ion-card-content>
</ion-card>
```

NEWS-DETAILS

TS

---

```
export class NewsDetailPage implements OnInit {

article

constructor(private newsService: NewsService) { }

ngOnInit() {
    this.article = this.newsService.currentArticle;
    console.log(this.article)
}
}
```

tabs.router.module.ts

---

```
 ....
{ path: 'news', loadChildren:'../news/news.module#NewsPageModule' },
{ path: 'news-detail', loadChildren:'../news-detail/news-detail.module#NewsDetailPageModule' },
....
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i resolved it:

```
ionViewWillEnter() {
    this.article = this.newsService.currentArticle;
    console.log(this.newsService.currentArticle)
}
```

Doing this it always change everytime as i do click on a new "news"